# Finding the area under a curve with respect of both $y$ and $x$

Tags: calculus, area

I have the following set of equations

$$y = 1$$
$$y = x ^{1/4}$$

from $x = 0$, to  $x = 1$

Now, I understand that the easiest way to do this is using the $x$ (question: **because we are cutting vertically right?**)

$$\int_0^1{1-(x^{1/4})}$$

However, is it possible to find the area under the curve with respect to $y$?

Comment: Yes. The two curves intersect at $(1,1)$ so you just have $\int_0^1y^4\,dy$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it is possible:
$$
\int_0^1 y^4 dy =\frac{1}{5}.
$$
The other integral is
$$
\int_0^1 x^{1/4} dx =\frac{4}{5}.
$$

The equality $\int_0^1 y^4 dy+\int_0^1 x^{1/4} dx=1$ is of course not just a coincidence.